# How to use custom object's list with typeconverter in winform?

Tags: winforms

I made custom type which can use in my custom winform control.
I want to display this custom type property in to default winform property window or my custom smart grid.
So i made type converter for my custom type.

> ```
> [Serializable]
> public class TestObj
> {
>     private int a;
>     private int b;
>     public int A { get { return a; } set { a = value; } }
>     public int B { get { return b; } set { b = value; } }
>
>     public TestObj()
>     {
>
>     }
>     public TestObj(int a, int b)
>     {
>         this.a = a;
>         this.b = b;
>     }
> }
> // TestObj Converter
> public class TestObjConverter : TypeConverter
> {
>     //can convert string -> testobj?
>     public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, > 
>       Type sourceType)
>     {
>         if (sourceType == typeof(string))
>         {
>             return true;
>         }
>         return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
>     }
>
>     // string -> TestObj
>     public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
>     {
>         if (value is string)
>         {
>             string[] v = ((string)value).Split(new char[] { ' ' });
>             return new TestObj(Int32.Parse(v[0]), Int32.Parse(v[1]));
>         }
>         return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
>     }
>
>     // TestObj -> string
>     public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
>       System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type
>      destinationType)
>     {
>         if (destinationType == typeof(string))
>         {
>             return ((TestObj)value).A + " " + ((TestObj)value).B;
>         }
>         return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
>     }
> }
> ```

(If i did not made this typeconverter then resx error will occurred.)
Now i can use TestObj type for my custom control's property.
But i want to use list collection property for this type in my custom control class.

> ```
>     private List<TestObj> testData = new List<TestObj>();
>
>     [Category("CustomControl"), Description("Property")]
>     [TypeConverter(typeof(TestObjConverter))]
>     public List<TestObj> TestData 
>     { 
>           get { return testData; } set { testData = value; } 
>     }
> ```

But i can not use this type's list for property.
If i use this, the collection editor was opened and i can add TestObj element too. But visual studio invoke error [invalid resx file,  Culture=newtral, PublicKeyTokrn=null ] when i compile this.

How to use my custom type list in winform property?

But

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late but someone else may run across this.  Your TestObj class that is being used for the property must be declared with the type converter and not the actual property you are exposing.  the property is typed with the class as any property should.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(TestObjConverter))]
public class TestObj
{
    ...
}
```

then in your main control class you just expose the property like normal without the type converter declaration like you have done

```
[Category("CustomControl"), Description("Property")]
public List<TestObj> TestData { get; set; }
```

I have several custom controls for winforms if you want a working example of this.  Just ask me and i will send one to you

Comment: Thanks but i think custom type converter will must implemented. Default TypeConverter will not know about  the type 'TestObj' so it can not be serialization or make design time code.

Comment: Did you make the changes i suggested?  Did you get an error?  It also looks like you are missing  a couple properties from your converter class.  GetProperties and GetPropertiesSupported should be implemented as well.